# Solving PDE system in Matlab: Derivatives on a mesh

Tags: matlab, mesh, pde

I am using MatLab to solve a system of coupled PDEs, with `pdenonlin`.

I create a mesh for my geometry (a square box with a circular hole in the middle), and refine it until I :

```
[p,e,t] = initmesh('DefectGeom2');
[p,e,t] = refinemesh('DefectGeom2',p,e,t);
```

I solve the system

```
% SOLUTION:
u = pdenonlin(b_s,p,e,t,c_s,a_s,f_s);

% EXTRACT different functions from the full solutions (systems):
np = size(p,2); % number of node points
uk = reshape(u,np,[]); % each uk column has one component of u
```

Therefore I now have my `uk` (in my case 3) solutions.

Now I want to calculate integrals and derivatives of this approximate solutions. I tried by interpolating to a uniform grid using `tri2grid`:

```
x=linspace(-1,1,Npts);
y=x;

psi=tri2grid(p,t,uk(:,3),x,y);
theta=tri2grid(p,t,uk(:,1),x,y);
theta_y=derivative(theta,1,2);
psi_x=derivative(psi,1,1);
```

and calculate:

```
pressure = trapz(x,psi_x-cos(2*theta).*theta_y+sin(2*theta));
```

But this gives me a poor approximation, I guess because of the fact that the grid is uniform whereas the mesh is finer around the central circle and coarser elsewhere.

Is there a way I could use MatLab built-in functions to calculate derivatives of the solutions of `pdenonlin` without brutally interpolate with `tri2grid` on a uniform grid?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `pdeInterpolant` class in the pde toolbox which might be useful. Use `meshToPet` to generate the input arguments from your mesh and then `evaluate` to query the interpolant.

You can specify a different grid when you query the interpolant so if you use a finer grid for this stage you might get better results without having to alter the original mesh.

Comment: Unfortunately I have MatLab R2014a, and `pdeInterpolant`  has been introduced more recently. Is there a workaround? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think the `pdeInterpolant` replaces the `trigrid` method that you're already using, so probably there isn't a builtin that you haven't already tried. You might get better results using `griddata` instead of `tri2grid` but odds are they will behave similarly. You could try breaking the problem space up into subregions and making a finer grid for the region near the hole? It would mean a lot of bookkeeping but if the brute force approach isn't an option then it might be worth the effort...